# Total sum of live changinput values

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, live, onkeyup

At first I have to apologize for my English. Im not native speaker.

Im a beginner and dont know JS or jQuery extensions well.
Need to sum 3 input live changing values with unique ID.

I wish sum these values live too.
So i have to write something like

```
total = $('#sumOne').value+$('#sumTwo').value+$(#sumThree).value
```

As I said, i really dont know JS, i know that the row above is absolutely incorrect.

Could anyone help me and write some example of script?

Thanks a lot for your time and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parseInt($('#sumOne').val())+parseInt($('#sumTwo').val())+parseInt($(#sumThree).val());
```

You want:

```
this.value = ''; // straight JS, no jQuery
```

or

```
$(this).val(''); // jQuery
```

With `$(this).value = ''` you're assigning an empty string as the value property of the jQuery object that wraps this -- not the value of this itself.

reference **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

Answer (score 0):

use `.val()` function to extract the value attribute of the jquery object. And do `parseInt` on the values before adding. Otherwise the values will get concatinated instead of addition.

```
var total = parseInt($('#sumOne').val())+parseInt($('#sumTwo').val())+parseInt($(`#sumThree`).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
 parseFloat($('#sumOne').val()) + parseFloat($('#sumTwo').val()) + parseFloat($(#sumThree).val())
```

Also convert values to float, using `parseFloat`

Answer (score 0):

as reference to Rituraj's answer,
its better to convert val() to int or float before adding them:

```
var total=parseFloat($('#sumOne').val())+parseFloat($('#sumTwo').val())+parseFloat($('#sumThree').val());
```